# How do I update MySQL database from Swagger

Tags: mysql, node.js, swagger

I have this problem. I want to have this data updated from Swagger 'Try out' on Swagger documentation and everything.
My REST api is written in Node.Js with the backend in Mysql.
Now here is what, The Code if tested on Postman works perfectly well. Now i want to use the Swagger to test if it works, it gives me The usual positive response, But it does not even effect anything on the Database. the base 64 String, tested from postman updates good , but from swagger, Does not work fine.

My code is looking like this

```
/** 
 * @swagger 
 * /auth/update_profile: 
 *   put: 
 *     description: Update Profile 
 *     parameters: 
 *     - name : id
 *       description: Login ID
 *       in: formData
 *       type: String
 *     - name: user 
 *       description: Login User 
 *       in: formData 
 *       type: String  
 *     - name : pass
 *       description: Login pass
 *       in: formData
 *       type: String
 *     - name : fullname
 *       description: users fullname
 *       in: formData
 *       type: String
 *     - name : base64string
 *       description: profile picture
 *       in: formData
 *       type: String
 *       
 *     responses:  
 *       200: 
 *         description: Update Profile
 */

app.put('/auth/update_profile', function (req, res) {
    var base64image = req.body.base64image;
    var id = req.body.id;
    var user = req.body.user;
    var pass = req.body.pass;
    var fullname = req.body.fullname;

    dbConn.query('update users set user =?, pass=?, fullname=?, base64image=? where id=?', [user, pass, fullname, base64image, id], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error: false, data: results, message: 'Update Successful' });
    })
})
```

Please What Do I appear to be doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this

```
*     - name : base64string
 *       description: profile picture
 *       in: formData
 *       type: String
```

With this

```
*     - name : base64image
 *       description: profile picture
 *       in: formData
 *       type: String
 *
```

Solved this problem swagger really looks up the names. Changing that works fine.